# How to run PDFbox at terminal

Tags: command-line, java, signature

I installed [*libpdfbox-java*](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) as [this `apt` instructions](https://howtoinstall.co/package/libpdfbox-java), `sudo apt install libpdfbox-java`.

Now, how to use it? can I run something as `ShowSignature myDoc.pdf` at terminal?
 **How to run it?**

---

### Notes

If a specialized answer is difficult, we can explode the question into steps:

1. **Where the path?** to, perhaps, use some *ugly* long `java -jar magicPath/pdfbox-app-ETC.jar` (**no pretty Ubuntu `cmd`  to use it?**)
2. How to check version, `cmd --version`?
3. ... them, perhaps, if `apt` installed version 2+, I can use Apache instructions of https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html or https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/commandline.html

**Motivation**: I am using `pdfsig myDoc.pdf` but it say *"Certificate Validation: Certificate issuer is unknown."*, that is a software bug... So people suggested to use PDFbox.